# Find all positive integers m, n, p such that $(m+n)(mn+1)=2^p$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all positive integers m, n, p such that

$$(m+n)(mn+1)=2^p$$

Please give me some hints

Thanks

Comment: I proved m+1=t2^s, n-1=q2^s with t, q are odd numbers

But ... . Just that

Comment: what is $s$????

Comment: Is $p$ prime ? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: No, p is a positive number

Comment: @tangkhaihanh: This is true for any integer...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik
I mean 2^s divides m+1 but 2^{s+1} not divides m+1

Comment: Are you looking for those $p$ such that the relation you wrote holds given certain integers $m$ and $n$? In this case, you could start dividing the cases where $m$ and/or $n$ are even/odd...

Comment: @Michalis 
No, m+1=t2^s, n-1=q2^s with t, q are odd numbers. Same "s"

Comment: oh I see, sorry

Comment: @GIANCANE
Find m, n and p :(

Comment: OK but they are related because of the relation you want! I mean, fixing $m$ and $n$ then you find the possible $p$. For example if $m$ is even and $n$ odd, there's no $p\geq 1$ satisfying the relation...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elementary Diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363313/elementary-diophantine-equation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $m+n=2^a$ and $mn+1=2^b$ with $a+b=p$. First note that both $m$ and $n$ need to be odd.

**First case**: Suppose $m=1$ or $n=1$, then the other is equal to $2^{p/2}-1$  and this is a solution for even $p$.

Now suppose $m>1$ so $b>a>1$. Adding the two equations above we get
$(m+1)(n+1)=mn+1+m+n=2^a(2^{b-a}+1)$. Let $m+1=2^xw$ and $n+1=2^zy$ with $w,y$ odd, $x,z>0$ and $x+z=a$. Then $2^a=2^xw+2^zy-2$, so one of $x$ or $z$ needs to be $1$ (if both were $>1$ the RHS would be $\equiv 2\mod 4$.

**Case $x=1$:** We have $x+z=a$, so $z=a-1$. The equation for $2^a$ becomes
$$
2^a=2w+2^{a-1}y-2\geq 2^{a-1}y.
$$
This implies $y=1$, since it is odd. We get $m-1=2w-2=2^{a-1}$ and $n+1=2^z=2^{a-1}$ and indeed this gives a solution.

**Case $z=1$:** The same just with $m$ and $n$ swapped.

So the only solutions are $m=1$ and $y=2^{p/2}-1$ and 
$(m,n)=(2^k\pm 1,2^k\mp 1)$

Comment: "so one of x or y needs to be 1"
must "x or z" ?

Comment: @tangkhaihanh: Yeah. Sorry for the notational difficulties here, I changed it while I was writing the answer. I hope my solution is correct but it's probably not the most elegant.

Comment: Please consider and describe in addition case $(m,n)=(2^k\pm 1, 2^k\mp 1)$. then $(m+n)(mn+1) = 2^{3k+1}$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
Examples:
$$(1+3)(1\cdot 3 +1) = 2^4;$$
$$(3+5)(3\cdot 5 +1) = 2^7;$$
$$(7+9)(7\cdot 9 +1) = 2^{10};$$
$$(15+17)(15\cdot 17 +1) = 2^{13};$$
$$...$$

Comment: @Oleg567, yes, i am wondering

Comment: @Oleg567: Thank you! I forgot one crucial case! I'll add it.