# Solution Of Diophantine Equations.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $(x+y)(xy+1)=2^z$

Now as $2$ is a prime number we get $x+y=2^a$ and $xy+1=2^b$ for some natural numbers $a$ and $b$. Now as $xy+1>x+y$ for every $x, y>1$. So we get $2^b>2^a=> b>a=> 2^a|2^b$. So $x+y|xy+1$. Now let $p$ be a common prime factor of $x$ and $y$, then $p$ divides $x+y$, so $p$ divides $xy+1$ but as $p$ divides $x$ and $y$ so $p$ divides $xy$. So we get $p$ divides $1$, so there is no common factor of $x$ and $y$.

Now what i do from here?

Comment: Just thinking out loud: Since $x + y = 2^a$ then $y = 2^a - x$ and $xy + 1 = 2^b$ gives the quadratic $x^2 - 2^a x + (2^b - 1) = 0$. Solving this quadratic for $x$ gives $x = 2^{a-1} \pm \sqrt{2^{2a - 2} - 2^b + 1}$. So we want that $2^{2a - 2} - 2^b + 1 = z^2$ for some integer $z$. This may lead nowhere, I don't see how to continue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elementary Diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363313/elementary-diophantine-equation)

Answer (score 0):

You have $xy=2^k-1$ for some integer $k> 0$

Note that with $x=1$ and $y=2^k-1$ you get $$(x+y)(xy+1)=2^{2k}$$
So we always have that solution.

We also have other solutions if we can factor $2^k-1$ into two integers whose sum is a power of $2$

For example with $k=4$ we get $2^{k}-1=3(5)$ where $3+5=2^3$  so $(x+y)(xy+1)=2^{7}$

Comment: A minor point is since the equation is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, any solution $(x,y)$ also has the corresponding solution $(y,x)$. Thus, $x = 2^k - 1$ and $y$ is also a solution.

Comment: Yes, of course we also have $(y,x)$ for each $(x,y)$